# Dropdown UITextfield animation

Tags: objective-c, animation, uiview, uitextfield

Currently I have a "sign up with email" button that hides and shows a view containing 3 UITextfields when clicked.

```
- (IBAction)hideButton:(id)sender {
[self.emailSignUp setHidden:YES];
[self.emailView setHidden:NO];
[self.signUp setHidden:NO];}
```

I'd like to add an animation for the text fields to drop down for when the button is tapped.   Is this possible?  If it is could you please provide some sample code?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried adding animation or just want sample to add ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the Block-based [UIView animationWith...] methods and change the frame of your views or you can do something like
`[UIView beginAnimations:@"Animation" context:NULL];`
// Assumes the your view is just off the bottom of the screen.
        `self.textView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.textView.frame, 0, -self.TextView.frame.size.height);`
`[UIView commitAnimations];`

Comment: I'd use to set the alpha instead of the height.

Comment: I thought you where interested in sliding views into place. The code snippet above moves the view by its height up by changing its frame property.

Comment: Yes you're totally right. I got distracted by `self.TextView.frame.size.height`.

Comment: Fine. I'd suggest you go with the block base animation methods from UIView. Simply write UIView animat and autocompletion will show the options you have. (delay, completion, options etc.).

Comment: pls. Don't forget to vote it up or mark your question as being solved.

Comment: I believe you think I was asking for it..?